# How to install libssl3.so on amazon linux 2?

Tags: linux, openssl, centos, libreoffice, amazon-ami

I have container built off an amazon linux 2 image.
Im running into this error when trying to run libreoffice on command line

> /opt/libreoffice7.4/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared
> libraries: libssl3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory

I do not see libssl3.so installed in the instance.   I've tried installing openssl openssl-devel, to no avail.  How do i install this library on an Amazon Linux 2 image? Im thinking Fedora/centos/rhat will suffice also.